# delay between requests - pagination requests violate api rate limit node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, rate-limiting

I have a while loop in a function which I use to query an API web service. The loop handles the pagination in the responses from the API server so the function can return all the entries in the database.

I need to adapt to rate limiting from the web service. The best way may be to set up a delay between the requests. How can I add a delay of 1000ms between each of the requests that handle pagination in this function?

```
var db = new Discogs().database();


const getALL = async (id) => {

    let releases = [];
    let currentPage = 1;
    let totalPages = null

    while (totalPages === null || currentPage < totalPages) {
        
        let response = db.getArtistReleases(id);
        let results = await response;

        if (totalPages === null) {
            totalPages = parseInt(results.pagination.pages);
        }

        releases.push(results);
        currentPage++;

    }

    return Promise.all(releases);
}
```

I execute the function in my app's backend API call

```
    const response = getAll(
        req.body.artistId
    );

    response.then(results => {
     
    })
    .catch((error) => {

    });
```

Comment: typically endpoints with rate limiting will pass back headers telling you were you currently stand against the limit. Also Id get rid of the while loop. 

If I were to approach this problem id start with promises or a recursive loop.  Then if I needed more control id implement some sort of queueing system. In that queue you could add supplemental logic to handle checking the previous rate limit data before sending the next request here you could add backoff logic or just requeue the request on a delay (you could use settimeout to add delay). If you have more questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To adapt to the API's rate limit I rewrote the function that handles the pagination and api library calls after [this solution](https://fdalvi.github.io/blog/2021-06-11-consume-paginated-apis/)

Also added the [sleep(ms)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pause-in-node-js-for-a-specific-time/) function to pause execution for a given number of seconds if the rate limit is being approached.

```
    const getAll = async (id) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {


            let mainReleases = []
            let perMinuteRateLimit = 60;
            let rateLimitThrottleSeconds = 4;
            let latestResults;


            db.getArtistReleases(id, {page: 1, per_page: 75}, (err, results, rateLimit)  => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Discogs API Error: " + err);
                }

                latestResults = results;
                mainReleases.push(latestResults.releases);

                async.whilst(
                    (cb) => cb(null, latestResults['pagination'].urls.next),
                    (iteration_cb) => {
                        var q = url.parse(latestResults['pagination'].urls.next, true);
                        
                        console.log("Discogs API - Artist Releases Query Page " + q.query['page'] + " of " + latestResults['pagination'].pages + "...");

                        db.getArtistReleases(id, {page : q.query['page']}, (err, res, rateLimit)  => {
         
                            latestResults = res;
                            mainReleases.push(latestResults.releases);


                            if (rateLimit['used'] > perMinuteRateLimit*0.9) {
                                sleep(rateLimitThrottleSeconds * 1000).then(() => {
                                    console.log("near Discogs API rate limit -- throttling requests\n" + JSON.stringify(rateLimit));
                                    iteration_cb(null, res);
                                });
                            } else {
                                iteration_cb(null, res);
                            }
                    });
                    
                    },
                    (err, results) => {
                        resolve(mainReleases);
                    }
                )
            });
        });
    };

    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
```

queueing looks like a great solution but with this I was able to get the results I needed quickly at the expense of scalability probably.